# Infyom adminlte Yajra table buttons are displayed as crud.add_new and auth.app.create instead of button labels like 'add new' or 'create'

Tags: laravel-8, yajra-datatable, infyom

I am using php 8.75 with laravel 8, I followed InfyOM adminlte to create crud.

```
    composer entries

    "infyomlabs/adminlte-templates": "^3.0",
    "infyomlabs/generator-builder": "^1.0",
    "infyomlabs/laravel-generator": "^3.0",

    "yajra/laravel-datatables-buttons": "^4.13",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-html": "^4.41",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "^9.21"
```

my buttons are displaying as auth.app.create, auth.app.export, auth.app.print, auth.app.reset, auth.app.reload

how to fix these?

I ran NPM RUN DEV, but didnt work.

I want to see normal labels on buttons like create, export etc.